# How do you install g++ (at least version 4.1) on a solaris sparc server?

Tags: solaris, installation, sparc, g++

How do you install g++ (at least version 4.1) on a solaris sparc server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GNU folks don't have a Solaris package appropriate to your OS & architecture check www.sunfreeware.com -- I don't believe they have GCC 4.x, but you can grab a 3.x version and boostrap 4.x with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Solaris 10 or OpenSolaris, www.blastwave.org has 4.3.4 (CSWgcc4, I believe.).

Answer (score 2):

You can get gcc and g++ from OpenCSW project (http://www.opencsw.org).

Comment: The current version from OpenCSW is 4.3.3.

http://www.opencsw.org/packages/gcc4core

Comment: It has been upgraded to 4.6.2.